# \citeA does not propose elements of the library

Tags: bibtex, apacite

My question is: I use BibTex and the apacite style bibliography. It works fine and when I use \cite or \citeauthor I get the elements from my bibliography proposed. But when I want to use \citeA I get no proposals. The command works when I type the abbreviation in by hand. I checked Options/ autocompletion but I did not find which cwl field to check. I tried apacite.cwl, cite.cwl and others that seemed sensible.

I would appreciate your help!

Comment: This is a question about your editor, not about `apacite`. The question you seem to be asking is why does your editor not give you a list of possible entries from your `.bib` file when you use the cite commands defined by `apacite`. I would assume it's because it doesn't know about them. What editor are you using?

Comment: @Alan Munn Thank you for your quick answers! I use TexStudio. My first thought was also that the editor does not know the command but apparently it does as it works fine if I use \citeA{..} and enter the abbrevation of my bib element myself. The problem is that there are no automatic proposals which I have when using \cite. Therefore I thought the autocompletion is responsible for the problem and I need to activate the command (the right *.cwl document) but I could not find it.